# Projective plane and some curves

Tags: geometry, combinatorics

We define a line in the projective plane as a set of the form $$
L_{a,b,c}  = \left\{ {\left[ {x,y,z} \right] \in P_R^2 :ax + by + cz = 0} \right\}\text{ or just }L
$$
Let a finite collection of lines $$
\left\{ {L_i } \right\}_{i = 1}^n 
$$
such that $$
\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n {L_i } 
$$
it´s empty
The last definition.. a point $$
p \in \left\{ {L_i } \right\}_{i = 1}^n 
$$
it´s said to be a k-point if it´s exactly contained in k lines of $$
\left\{ {L_i } \right\}_{i = 1}^n 
$$
Prove that:
$$
t_2  \geqslant 3 + \sum\limits_{k \geqslant 4} {\left( {k - 3} \right)t_k } 
$$
where $ t_k $ is the amount of k-points. And the equality holds iff the corresponding paving is by triangles ( every such kind of sets define a natural paving by polygons)

This problem looks so difficult, I have no idea how to attack this problem Dx
This problem scares me , if someone can help me )=

Comment: If you remove the «homework difficult problem?» from the title nothing is lost...

Answer (score 1):

Look into what is known as the Sylvester-Gallai Theorem, and combinatorial approaches to proving it.